# How to load data employee on view GetAllEmpDetails.cshtml based on drop down selected index changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

I work on MVC web application using c# by ado.net I face issue I can't display employee data based on drop down selected index changed .

so

if user select Pending Request from drop down list it will select employee that have select employee status 1 .

if user select Done Request from drop down list it will select employee that have select employee status 2 .

my code as below :

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [EmployeeStatus] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployeeName], [EmployeeStatus]) VALUES (1211, N'ahmed', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployeeName], [EmployeeStatus]) VALUES (1222, N'eslam', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployeeName], [EmployeeStatus]) VALUES (1223, N'adel', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployeeName], [EmployeeStatus]) VALUES (1224, N'mohamed', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployeeName], [EmployeeStatus]) VALUES (1225, N'mosh', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployeeName], [EmployeeStatus]) VALUES (1227, N'ali', 1)
```

stored procedures have logic

```
create Procedure [dbo].[LoadDropDownEmployee] 
@EmployeeStatus int
as  
begin  
   select * from Employee  where EmployeeStatus=@EmployeeStatus
End 

create Procedure [dbo].[GetEmployees]  
as  
begin  
   select *from Employee  
End
```

Employee Model

```
public class EmpModel
        {

            public int EmployeeId { get; set; }


            public string EmployeeName { get; set; }


            public int EmployeeStatus { get; set; }

          

        }
```

Employee Repository have functions for controller

```
public List<EmpModel> GetAllEmployees()
{
    connection();
    List<EmpModel> EmpList = new List<EmpModel>();


    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("GetEmployees", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    con.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();   
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

        EmpList.Add(

            new EmpModel
            {

                EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EmployeeId"]),
                EmployeeName = Convert.ToString(dr["EmployeeName"]),
                EmployeeStatus = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EmployeeStatus"])

            }
            );
    }

    return EmpList;
}
public List<EmpModel> LoadDropDownLists(int EmployeeStatus)
{
    connection();
    List<EmpModel> EmpList = new List<EmpModel>();


    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("LoadDropDownEmployee", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    com.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    com.Parameters["@EmployeeStatus"].Value = EmployeeStatus;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    con.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();  
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

        EmpList.Add(

            new EmpModel
            {

                EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EmployeeId"]),
                EmployeeName = Convert.ToString(dr["EmployeeName"])

            }
            );
    }

    return EmpList;
}
```

controller Employee

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult LoadDropDownList(int EmployeeStatus)
        {

            EmpRepository EmpRepo = new EmpRepository();
            return View();
        }
public ActionResult GetAllEmpDetails()
        {

            EmpRepository EmpRepo = new EmpRepository();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(EmpRepo.GetAllEmployees());
        }
}
```

view GetAllEmpDetails.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Ado.netMvc.Models.EmpModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetAllEmpDetails";
}

<h2>GetAllEmpDetails</h2>

<th>
    <select class="form-control" id="statusselect" name="statusselectName">
        <option>Select Status</option>
        <option>Pending Request</option>
        <option>All requests </option>
    </select>
</th>



<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeStatus)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeStatus)
            </td>

        </tr>



    }

</table>
```

**so How to get data on view `GetAllEmpDetails` when drop down `statusselect` selected index changed  ?**

Comment: you need to create a Html.Action for loading all employees. Then on select-input change need to call ajax which will call the Html.Action and send the raw html depending on the selected employee and then render it to the main view.

Comment: can you show me please how to make that ajax call by code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move the employee list to a partial view. So the  **GetAllEmpDetails.cshtml** view will be like the below. The ajax call on the main view to render the partial view from the ActionResult method GetAllEmpDetailsByStatus of Employee Controller. Also I add value to the option of the select input. Because we need to pass this value to the **GetAllEmpDetailsByStatus** method and filter the employee data.

```
@model IEnumerable<Ado.netMvc.Models.EmpModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetAllEmpDetails";
}
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#statusselect").change(function () {

              var postData = {
                  empStatus: $(this).val()
                };
                //addAntiForgeryToken(postData);

                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../Employee/GetAllEmpDetailsByStatus',
                    data: postData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#employeeContainer").html(data.html);
                    },
                    failure: function () {

                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
<h2>GetAllEmpDetails</h2>
<th>
    <select class="form-control" id="statusselect" name="statusselectName">
        <option value="1">Select Status</option>
        <option value="2">Pending Request</option>
        <option value="0">All requests </option>
    </select>
</th>

<div id="employeeContainer">
  @Html.Partial("_AllEmployee", Model)
</div>
```

The Partial View below

```
@model IEnumerable<Ado.netMvc.Models.EmpModel>

<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            Employee Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Employee Name
        </th>
        <th>
             Employee Status
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeStatus)
            </td>

        </tr>



    }

</table>

The GetAllEmpDetailsByStatus() ActionResult method of EmployeeController is like the below.



public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult GetAllEmpDetailsByStatus(int empStatus)
         {
        
               EmpRepository EmpRepo = new EmpRepository();
               ModelState.Clear();
               var theData= EmpRepo.LoadDropDownLists(empStatus);
               
               return Json(new
               {
                  html = RenderPartialViewToString("_AllEmployee", theData)
               });
          }
    
     // Better to move the base class, like BaseController.

     public virtual string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    
            this.ViewData.Model = model;
    
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(this.ControllerContext, viewName);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: i test solution i get error The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /employee/

Comment: so how to solve issue

Comment: Does your partial view render correctly? Does ajax hit the controller's action method?